# NSDecimalNumber does not display values in console

Tags: xcode, nsdecimalnumber, xcode9.1, xcode-debugger

I'm using Xcode 9.1 and when I try to display the NSDecimalNumber values in Xcode debugger console, it prints it out like this.

```
po amount
0x0000000147354340
```

However when I use NSLog(@"%@", amount) it displays the correct number in the console.

I recall this used to work before, did something change or is there another way to print NSDecimalNumber values in the console

Comment: Not reproducible for me with Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through a few SO articles, I found that disabling the 'Address Sanitizer' it started working again for me.